# Get request URI in jinja2?

Tags: pylons, jinja2

I'm working on a Pylons project using Jinja2 templating. I want to test for the request URI and/or controller inside the Jinja2 templates - is there an equivalent to a getRequestUri() call? I can set a context variable as a flag inside all the controller methods to do what I want, but that seems a bit like writing my home address on each and every one of my house keys...  i.e. not quite the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: not quite a function call, but I can test against url.environ.PATH_INFO. It only gives me the URL path, not the hostname, and I don't know that it would give me the query string, but it gives me what I need.